Apply Bayes' Rule to a joint, prior distribution?
The problem is how to update a joint prior distribution consisting of two independent variables with observed evidence?

For the prior distribution, data exists for average event frequency (i.e., average number of occurrences within a given time duration) and average durations (how long did each event last on average).  For example, when grid electric power was lost and for how long. It seems reasonable to assume that the 1st variable is Poisson process for random event occurrences (time when event occurs, t1). The 2nd variable is average duration (time, t2) that could be some other distribution subject to the condition that duration (time) can never be less than or equal to zero, perhaps an exponential distribution.

The evidence for the likelihood function will also be a set of observed times for the occurrence of the event and time duration of each event.


What are some distributions that can be used for the joint prior and the likelihood functions? Some articles suggest that a compound Poisson process may be used to describe the prior and a doubly stochastic Markov process for the likelihood.
How does one obtain a posterior distribution using Bayes' Rule?  I do not know the math to do this stepwise.
A method that uses conjugate priors and does not necessitate the use of numerical methods is preferred.
